# How do you import non-node.js files?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I load external js files that don't fit the node.js format. I am trying to import the json serialize library. How can I do this?

Comment: theres builtin support for json (e.g. JSON.stringify(obj)), are you looking for something beyond the already supported feature set?

Comment: @david Just for now and future reference. I don't want to have to find node.js versions of everything.

Comment: Definitely don't import a second JSON library (I'm assuming you're looking at json2.js?).  JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify() are both built into node from the start.

Comment: @Will03uk What do you mean by "don't fit the node.js format"?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

2 answers...

1) the JSON object is built-in to node.js, so you can just call JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify(), there is no need to import external code for this particular case.

2) to import external code, node.js follows the CommonJS module specification and you can use require()

so if you have a file called external.js (in the same directory as the rest of your code):

```
this.hi = function(x){ console.log("hi " + x); }
```

and from node you do:

```
var foo = require("./external");
foo.hi("there");
```

you will see the output `hi there`

Answer (score 13):

If you trust the code (I mean, **really** trust the code) then you can `eval` it:

```
eval(require('fs').readFileSync('somefile.js', 'utf8'));
```

I wouldn't recommend doing this with remote code (because it could change without your knowledge) but if you have a local copy of something then it should be fine.

Comment: This is a horrible answer. And I love it.

Comment: A simple require as in the accepted answer works better than reading a JSON. Also it is beneficial if the JSON is a config file and you would like to inject it into your .js file using webpack, backpack, etc.

Comment: if it comes from a file you already trust it, in the same way you trust when doing `require()`

Answer (score 3):

Write wrappers or change the code.

What should automagically make it work? How's Node supposed to know which functions should get exported or not?

All you can do is to adjust the code to match the Common JS standard, but before you do that, check the [API Docs](http://nodejs.org/api.html) and the [Modules Pages](https://github.com/ry/node/wiki/Modules) on the Node.js Wiki, to see whether someone already did the job for you :)

If you write code yourself that should work in a Browser and Node.js you can use a wrapper like the following one:

```
(function(node) {
    // Your Awesome code here
    if (node) {
        exports.foo = ...

    } else {
        window.foo = ...
    }

})((function(){return ('' + this).slice(8, -1) !== 'DOMWindow';})());
```