# is there a require for json in node.js

Tags: json, node.js, require

I would like to include a couple of JSON files in my JavaScript code that are in the same directory as my JavaScript source file.

If I wanted to include another JavaScript file I could simply use `require`.
Now I'm using `readFileSync` and `__dirname` to get the JSON, which I think is an ugly way to do it.

Is there something similar for require that enables me to load a JSON file?

Comment: See this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662851/how-do-you-import-non-node-js-files

Comment: @coen What do you mean by "include a JSON file"? Read and parse it? If yes, possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726729/how-to-parse-json-using-nodejs

Comment: yes; read and parse. But this is specifically reading a *file*, similar to reading a js file, so this is no duplicate and goatslacker's answer is still valid.

Answer (score 610, accepted):

As of node v0.5.x yes you can require your JSON just as you would require a js file.

```
var someObject = require('./somefile.json')
```

In ES6:

```
import someObject from './somefile.json'
```

Comment: Is this true? It's not working for me, and https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1357 and https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/584 suggest it shouldn't.

Comment: those two tickets are 1 and 2 years old. JSON require was added in node 0.5.

Comment: You need to use require('./somefile.json') assuming the file is in the same directory (note the dot and slash).

Comment: There's one gotcha with this. The result will be cached! So if you for some reason need to load the data again (say at a cronjob), you'll get the same old result.

Comment: @bebraw I cannot seem to reproduce that on node 0.10.x, are you sure?

Comment: @CamiloMartin Yes, absolutely sure. Try creating some JSON file, load it through Node REPL, modify JSON and load again. It should yield the first results.

Comment: @bebraw Ah! But that's totally different, expected, and in compliance with the docs. I'm not going to use a `config.json` file as if it was a database, adding and removing stuff at run-time. But if I restart the server, all changes will be taken in at the next run - the same is true for all the javascript you're using; configuration is like variables in your code.

Comment: @CamiloMartin Yeah, it's alright to use `require` in that case. I agree.

Comment: Note : the extension `.json` seem to matter

Comment: well formed json helps too

Comment: Just as a note, if you did want a different file other than `.json` to be parsed as json, you could teach require how to read it.
`require.extensions['.har'] = require.extensions['.json']; var blar = require('./file.har');` will now be treated as json

Comment: Just to clarify this works the same for normal is imports in the sense the import is cached. Eg if I have a JSON file (a), file (b) references file (a). And file (c) references file (a) and(b).  The (a) import will only be loaded once right ( same as normal as imports) using `import * from ./data-file-a.json`

Comment: With TS I was need to add flags: `--resolveJsonModule` `--esModuleInterop`

Answer (score 70):

JSON files don’t require an explicit exports statement. You don't need to export to use it as Javascript files.

So, you can use just `require` for valid JSON document.

*data.json*

```
{
  "name": "Freddie Mercury"
}
```

*main.js*

```
var obj = require('data.json');

console.log(obj.name); 
//Freddie Mercury
```

Answer (score 53):

Two of the most common way to **import**

First way :

```
let jsonData = require('./JsonFile.json')
```

`let jsonData = require('./JsonFile')` // if we omitting .json also works

OR

```
import jsonData from ('./JsonFile.json')
```

Second way :

1. synchronously

   ```js
   const fs = require('fs')
   let jsonData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('JsonFile.json', 'utf-8'))
   ```
2. asynchronously

   ```js
   const fs = require('fs')
   let jsonData = {}
   fs.readFile('JsonFile.json', 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
     if (err) throw err

     jsonData = JSON.parse(data)
   })
   ```

**Note:**

1. If JsonFile.json is changed, we do not get the new data, even if we re-run `require('./JsonFile.json')`
2. The `fs.readFile` or `fs.readFileSync` will always re-read the file, and get changes

Comment: Note that the fs method uses the directory where node was launched from as a starting point, not the directory where the source code doing the read resides, whereas the "require" method uses the path relative to the importing source code location. So you will have differences in paths between the two methods as soon as you store things in different folders.

Comment: >> if we omitting .json also works <<

Better to not omit `.json`, because node will try to load `.js` file, so it can lead to bugs.

Answer (score 25):

No. Either use `readFile` or `readFileSync` (The latter only at startup time).

Or use an existing library like

- [cjson](https://github.com/kof/node-cjson)

Alternatively write your config in a js file rather then a json file like

```
module.exports = {
  // json
}
```

Comment: @coen yes, we always use `__dirname` to make relative paths.

Comment: Ran into this where it will import JSON locally but not in the docker container on my EC2 instance in AWS... Instead of trying to configure mime types and what not, I just switched to JS instead of JSON. Hope this may help someone.

Comment: This answer is straight up incorrect, you should either update or remove it.

Answer (score 10):

A nifty non-caching async one liner for node 15 modules:

```js
import { readFile } from 'fs/promises';

const data = await readFile('{{ path }}').then(json => JSON.parse(json)).catch(() => null);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can import json files by using the node.js v14 experimental json modules flag. More details [here](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_experimental_json_modules)

*file.js*

```
import data from './folder/file.json' assert { type: 'json' }

export default {
  foo () {
    console.log(data)
  }
}
```

And you call it with `node --experimental-json-modules file.js`

Comment: I got this error:  `TypeError [ERR_IMPORT_ASSERTION_TYPE_MISSING]: Module "src/__tests__/operations.json" needs an import assertion of type "json"`

Answer (score 7):

You even can use **require** of your JSON without specifying the extension *.json*.
It will let you change the file extension to *.js* without any changes in your imports.

assuming we have *./myJsonFile.json* in the same directory.

```
const data = require('./myJsonFile')
```

If in the future you'll change *./myJsonFile.json* to *./myJsonFile.js* nothing should be changed in the import.

Comment: This is confusing.  Your proposed example of wanting to change the json require to a js require is a stretch of the imagination.  Your answer should just stick to the facts and avoid the hypothetical scenario.  I also suggest that your hypothetical filename `./myJsonFile.js` is confusing. 
 Why would it be called "myJsonFile" if it has a .js extension?  Additional useful fact though: if you do `require('./file')` and both `file.js` and `file.json` exist, then it will use `file.js`.

Comment: Found useful that you may supress the file extension `.json`. Thnks

Answer (score 4):

In ES6:

```
import someObject from './somefile.json' assert {type: 'json'};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a module to create a require.

```
import { createRequire } from 'module'
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url)
const foo = require('./foo.json')
```

Comment: This is a good answer. Although you should require `foo.json` not `foo.js`

Answer (score -1):

Simply use the JSON object from Node; you don't need import it. See usage below:

```
const jsonifiedObject = JSON.parse(an_array or a_object)
or
JSON.stringify(object)
```

Hope that helps..

Comment: The question was about getting the data from disk. Your solution is applicable when the data is already loaded

Answer (score -2):

if you are **using typescript**, you can just **add in your tsconfig.json** a new field called **resolveJsonModule: true**, and then you can import all the informations of any .json file just like this:

`import * as jsonfile from "./path/to/json"`