# Save a JSON file to server in express (node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Having this function in express that writes a JSON file on a folder

```
var savingtheJson=function(path, jsonObject, callback){
  jsonfile.writeFile(file2, jsonO, callback);
}
```

I will like to know how can I access/read this file from the browser once is saved.

If I do this:

```
savingtheJson('/json/myfile.json', jsonObj, function(){
            console.log("done it!");
        });
```

When I go to the browser and I type:

```
http://localhost:8080/json/myfile.json
```

Of course I get an error from express "Cannot Get ...." cause I think is trying to resolve it like an specific request

How can I store this file into the static folder declared for this goal 
(`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')`)?

How can I access this file once is saved?

Comment: The static service directory is in '/public', just like you mentioned. But IMO you should instead provide a new endpoint in your web service for retrieving the file.

Comment: You mean to create and endpoint on the app that reads the file like using this kind os function on this example?

[reading json file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703098/how-to-get-a-json-file-in-express-js-and-display-in-view)

Comment: You would definitely not read the file like that in a server application. I meant to create a new route (e.g. `/json/:myfile`) and asynchronously read the file there on GET.

Comment: you can load a json file to a variable by simply calling require!

Answer (score 13):

First you need to define which folder is going to be exposed as public, so that you can save your json file inside there.

You can use the built-in middleware [express.static](http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html) for this purpose.

Below in the example I have created a endpoint called `/users?name=wilson&age=32` which receives query data in order grab user's information as **name** and **age** for then you can save it as file named **person.json**.

So after you consume the above endpoint mentioned, you will be able to consume your file with something like `http://localhost:4040/person.json` successfully.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 4040;
var fs = require('fs');

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
  var name = req.query.name;
  var age = req.query.age;

  var person = {
    name: name,
    age: age
  };

  savePersonToPublicFolder(person, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(404).send('User not saved');
      return;
    }

    res.send('User saved');
  });
});

function savePersonToPublicFolder(person, callback) {
  fs.writeFile('./public/person.json', JSON.stringify(person), callback);
}

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('server up and running at port: %s', port);
});
```