# Keeping variables loaded / cached so they can be used by multiple requests.

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching

I'm not sure if this is possible, I'm assuming something like this is. I've got a couple of JSON files containing a series of JSON objects, each with a unique ID. I'd like to be able to use a Node application to read these objects and return all of the objects with an ID greater than a parameter provided.

ie. /after/20 would return all of the JSON objects from the file whose ID is greater than 20.

These requests will be happening very frequently, by lots of different users. Therefore, I was wondering if there is a way to store or cache these files in some way which means they don't need to be repeatedly loaded. Therefore making the process both quicker and more efficient.

Comment: How about you keep them in memory? How big is the dataset?

Comment: Not that large. In terms of size, only about 40mb each. So only 80mb in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that will keep the whole dataset in memory. I am assuming you have at least node 0.5 (to [require json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163061/is-there-a-require-for-json-in-node-js)), that the two json files are named `json1` and `json2` and I will use [express](http://expressjs.com/) because of its routing.

```
var express = require('express'),
http = require('http'),
json1 = require('./json1.json'),
json2 = require('./json2.json');

var app = express();

//Express config

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('port', 8080 );
    //...
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    //Right before the router, add a middleware to expose your objects
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
        req.json1 = json1;
        req.json2 = json2;
        next();
    });
    app.use(app.router);
    //...
});
```

Finally, any router will have access to both json objects.

```
app.get('/after/:id', function(req, res){
    var objects = req.json1,
        id = req.params.id,
        result = objects.filter(function(obj){ return obj.id >= id; });
    res.json(200, result);
});
```

Comment: That's perfect, thanks. I'll have a dabble with this tomorrow morning. Looks ideal for my requirements.

Comment: Worked perfectly. I had to make some minor alterations to fit the structure of the file but that was pretty much exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you use node.js's "require" function to load a module (or JSON file, in your case), it is cached based on its filename.

See [Node.JS API Doc](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) about this.

I am using this technique in a project with many small files and they all get cached after their first load.