# Parsing JSON directly from a file in node.js

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to parse a JSON file with the code below, but I am getting an error:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var sampleData = require("./sampleData.json");
var dataInArray = JSON.parse(sampleData.toString());
```

Here is the error:

```
$ node prog.js 

undefined:1
[object Object]
 ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (~/prog.js:3:24) //The line where I perform the JSON parsing
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your json code have a valid syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you require json with node, it is already parsed for you.
Just do

```
var sampleData = require("./sampleData.json");
console.log(Object.keys(sampleData));
```

and `sampleData` will be the object represented by the JSON.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163061/is-there-a-require-for-json-in-node-js).

**EDIT:** Be conscious when you do this, cause your data might be cached and not reload if multiple `require` occurs in your app. (See [node.js](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_caching) docs). 
If you change your data while the application is active, it might be better to use a regular `readFile` and `JSON.parse` to reload the data from scratch when you need it.

Comment: Well that's surprising. :-) I wouldn't have expected it to support straight JSON, but I suppose if it's `eval`'ing...