# how to include json file on node.js javascript file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I want to include json file on javascript in node application. I have include using `"require();"`. But i have face **error:**

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined".

Comment: No on client side Javascript you can't use `require` you can make `ajax` call to get JSON file's data.

Comment: see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163061/is-there-a-require-for-json-in-node-js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163061/is-there-a-require-for-json-in-node-js)

Comment: also if you are getting undefined - are you running this in a browser or as a server application?  see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 1):

In client side Javascript `require` won't work. Instead of this use [`jQuery.getJson()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

```
$.getJSON( "json_file.json", function( data ) {
   //data variable having your json data 
});
```

Comment: `$.getJSON` in `nodejs` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre: This is an xy question. The OP complains that javascript complains that `require` is not defined. That means he's not running his script in node. The OP is confused. This answer is probably correct.

Comment: Yes OP mentioned nodejs but actually he is trying to access JOSN at client side. @RayonDabre OP is confuse b/w Node and Javascript so he is trying Node's syntax in JS.