# How to import JSON file on Jest tests?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm testing my application using `Jest`, but it's getting an error like:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

The line witch's occurring error is:

```
import { something } from "../my-json.json";
```

How can I import the `JSON` file on Jest tests?

Comment: If you using that json as mock you could also store it as object in js file and export it. Just easy solution :P

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is there a require for json in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163061/is-there-a-require-for-json-in-node-js)

Answer (score 23):

As decribed here: [is there a require for json in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163061/is-there-a-require-for-json-in-node-js) you can use:

```
import someObject from ('./somefile.json')
```

This should also work:

```
const testObject = require('../config/object');
```

However, while i was using jest for testing i got it working by saving the json with .js extension and inside it using module.exports. Then i destructured the object in my main file.

- JSON file (object.js):

  ```
  module.exports = {
    "testObject":
    {
        "name": testName
        "surname": testSurname
    }
  }
  ```
- Main File

  ```
  const { testObject } = require('./config/object');
  ```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with `XML` files... `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

Answer (score 17):

Works with Typescript / `ts-jest 26.5` :

```
import * as myJson from './mock/MyJson.json';

...

const result = doAnyting(myJson);
```

Comment: japp, 

`import myJson from './mock/MyJson.json';` 

returned undefined for me. Changing to 


`import * as myJson from './mock/MyJson.json';`


did the trick with Typescript and ts-node

Comment: Same here, was testing Angular service, which imports json. `import * as myJson from './MyJson.json'` saved me.

Answer (score 13):

When using `Typescript` and `Vue CLI`, all I needed to do was to add `resolveJsonModule` to `tsconfig.ts`:

```
// tsconfig.ts

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
  }
}
```

---

This in fact solves the loading of JSON files by Typescript in general.

Note: I am using `Vue CLI` so it is possible that some JSON related config is already preconfigured there.

Answer (score 6):

You need to `import json from 'filename.json'`. Make sure that if you're using path alias you need to configure them on your `jest.config.js` file inside the `ModuleNameMapper` config.

Answer (score 2):

```
const myJSON = require('./json_file_name.json')
```

Note that `myJSON` is already an object, no need to use `JSON.parse`

Comment: If its an object then why did you name it *JSON?

Answer (score 1):

```
const someObject = require('./somefile.json')
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `"esModuleInterop": true,` in `tsconfig.spec.json` compilerOptions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove ',' before all the '}'. I found this solution by test and error.

Comment: Please be more descriptive.

Comment: The last attribute must not have a , after it