# jest test getting undefined for imported json files

Tags: json, reactjs, jestjs

I'm using JSON schema file for form creation and validation. When I'm going to test that component, in jest testing environment all imported `*.json` files getting undefined.

E.g.
`import schema from "./schema.json"` in test environment schema is undefined. Please let me know if anyone getting fixed this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: alternatively, have you tried using `const schema = require('./schema.json);`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46676238/how-to-import-json-file-on-jest-tests

Comment: oh, I forgot to try that :). Thanks, it's working now. But is there a way to use es6 `import` with jest for this case. That means any babel plugin or whatever?

Comment: @BenW I'm using create-react-app and it already using babel-jest but still `import` not working.

Comment: Have you tried `import * as schema from "./schema.json" `