# How to get json values using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I am trying to get json values using nodejs but not working.I have searched some question in stackoverflow related this but always I am getting [Object Object] like this.I do not know Why I am getting like this.Anyone can resolve this issue?

file.json:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "mr": "place",
        "kg": "time",
        "bh": "sec"
    }
}
```

extension.js:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var file = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("c:\\xampp\\htdocs\\projects\\file.json", "utf8"));
console.log(file);
```

This is not duplicate. I have tried many ways but not working.
Note:I am using this code inside my visual studio code extension.

Comment: When you `JSON.parse` the file, it turns it into a javascript object.  By default those get logged as [Object object].  You can try logging a specific thing (e.g. `console.log(file.scripts.mr);` So you are probably correctly parsing the file data.

Comment: Getting undefined

Answer (score 2):

In node, you can import JSON like a JavaScript file

```
const file = require('./file.json')
console.log(file)
```

See [is there a require for json in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163061/is-there-a-require-for-json-in-node-js) for more info

Answer (score 1):

```
const data = require("./file.json")
console.log(data.scripts)
```

Comment: Yes..Getting [Object Object]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out it is simple.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const paht = require('path');
console.log(paht.join(__dirname,'../file.json'));
let file = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(paht.join(__dirname,'../file.json'), "utf8"));
```

__dirname gives you the directory of your current file, I used **path.join** to make sure  I can go further.
I put the json file in upper directory in my case

Comment: My code is not working only inside my vscode extension

Comment: I don't think IDE makes an issue, it is simple solution and it is node specific not IDE specific, try this one out, I hope it will work

Comment: Are you saving the file with .vs extension ?

Comment: See : https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extensions

Comment: link is not available