# how to import data to gatbsy-config.js

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I would like to add data to gatbsy-config in order to use GraphQL to manage the data.

so I copied the gatbsy-config.js :

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Gatsby Default Starter`,
    description: `Kick off your next, great Gatsby project with this default starter. This barebones starter ships with the main Gatsby configuration files you might need.`,
    author: `@gatsbyjs`,
  },
}
```

and I replaced the `siteMetadata` with my data, and all work fine.

But I would like to use an json, or any file to store the data, and not put in the config directly, so I tried :

import data fron 'src/data/myData.json'

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    data: data
  },
}
```

but I get an error on the first like

```
import projects from 'src/data/myData.json';
                                                                       ^^^^^^^^
  SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

So it looks like I can't use import. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36326307/5385381

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your data file's directory is `src/data/`.

Let's say your data file is `config.js` and it includes

```js
const config = {
    title: `Gatsby Default Starter`,
    description: `Kick off your next, great Gatsby project with this default starter. This barebones starter ships with the main Gatsby configuration files you might need.`,
    author: `@gatsbyjs`
}

module.exports = config;
```

Then in your `gatsby-config.js` file you can import this file like below:

```js
const config = require('./src/data/config');

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: config.title,
    description: config.description,
    author: config.author
  },

}
```