# Visual StudioCode Intellisense after parsing Json file

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code, intellisense

My backend is built with express (so basically javascript). The backend is also able to save some data to .json files and use this data.

```
var data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("path/data.json"));
```

It would help me a lot, if Visual Studio Code would provide Intellisense for my ***data*** object (like suggesting all elements of this json file). Is there any addon for this kind of "problem" ?

Example:

```
{
    "owner": "testperson",
    "age": "30"
}
```

After parsing this json file (*exact way like* *on top*), it would be very helpful to have Intellisense after writing

```
data.
```

Comment: What does "suggesting all elements of this json file" mean?

Comment: I have updated my question with an example.

Comment: @Marco You could use JSDoc comments to define a special type for the data variable and mark the variable with that type. This is the link to the documentation for the functionality you need: https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html
VS Code does understand JSDoc comments out of the box.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is there a require for json in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163061/is-there-a-require-for-json-in-node-js)

Comment: @tevemadar You can use require to load a JSON file but the question was how to get intellisense for the content, which is not the case when using require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a built-in solution in VSCode exactly that manner. To get intellisense VSCode needs to know what the type of something is and for that you can use JSDoc comments, if you want to stick to JavaScript. These are understood by VSCode without any problem.
The snippet down below is applies to your given example.

```
/**
  * @typedef {Object} MyData
  * @property {string} owner
  * @property {number} age
*/

/**
  * @type {MyData}
*/
let data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("path/data.json"));
```

For further reading I refer to the [JSDoc docs](https://jsdoc.app/).