# How to Load a File for Testing with Jasmine Node?

Tags: javascript, bdd, jasmine

I have a simple JavaScript file, `color.js`, and a matching spec file, `colorSpec.js`.

**color.js:**

```
function Color() 
{

}
```

**colorSpec.js:**

```
require('./color.js');

describe("color", function() {
  it("should work", function() {
    new Color(255, 255, 255);
  });
});
```

When I run `jasmine-node colorSpec.js`, I get the following exception:

```
ReferenceError: Color is not defined
```

How can I get Jasmine to load my `color.js` file before running `colorSpec.js`?

Comment: I just found this question, which is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662851/how-do-you-import-non-node-js-files

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you could load your color.js in the colorSpec.js with a require(). I dont see how jasmine can guess all the dependencies without you telling jasmine what they are exactly in your spec file.
Edit : 
A quick and dirty solution , but maybe there is something builtin Jasmine to do that :

```
fs = require('fs')
myCode = fs.readFileSync('./color.js','utf-8') // depends on the file encoding
eval(myCode)
```

then your class should be available with jasmine

if you call require directly on your file i think you need to create a module and export it

Comment: I tried adding `require('./color.js');` at the top of my spec file but I'm still getting `RefereceError` exceptions.

Comment: This works, but it feels like `node.js` should have something built in that does this.  Still, thanks for the help.  Please let me know if you run across a different way of achieving this.

Comment: Hello! I i need to evaluate Angular or some other DOM/ Browser based library, then what can i do?? Window is not available in node! :(

Comment: what does require('fs') does?

Answer (score 19):

When using Jasmine Node, you'll want to export your object/function/class, in this case Color, as a node module. I like to try and make my modules work in both node or a browser, like so:

Folder Structure:

```
js
  - src/
      color.js
  - spec/
      colorSpec.js
```

**src/color.js**

```
/**
 * class Color
 *
 * @constructor
 */
function Color(red, green, blue)
{
    var current = [red, green, blue];

    this.getCurrent = function ()
    {
        return current;
    }
}

// Export node module.
if ( typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.hasOwnProperty('exports') )
{
    module.exports = Color;
}
```

**spec/colorSpec.js**

```
var Color = require('../src/color.js');

describe("Test the Color object", function() {
    var color = new Color(255, 255, 255);

    it('to verify that it can return a color.', function() {
        expect(color.getCurrent()).toContain(255);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. One question: can I omit the `module` existence checking logic? When can `module` be `undefined`?

Comment: If you never plan to run this in a browser, then yes.

Comment: hmm, I tried this method but I get  `TypeError: util.roundDecimal is not a function` The only way that works is to `exports.roundDecimal = function` but I can't because my script is read by something that doesn't what `exports` is

Comment: Seems like the export needed to be an object `module.exports = {
  roundDecimal: roundDecimal
 }`

Answer (score 5):

This is not how require works. Your `color.js` needs to define/export something. I will assume you use require.js here for sanity.

`color.js`

```
define('Color', function (require) {
  var Color = function () {};
  return Color;
});
```

Then in your spec:

```
var Color = require('color.js');
```

Comment: I honestly wasn't planning on using `require.js`.  I'm building a color library and I didn't want to force any dependencies on the people using it.  Your answer is probably the accepted way to do this, but it doesn't fit my project requirements.