# How to test my functions with gulp-jasmine, gulp-jasmine-browser or gulp-jasmine-phantom?

Tags: javascript, gulp, jasmine

I've got `gulp-jasmine-phantom` running, but I get a `ReferenceError: Tictactoe is not defined`. I have the feeling I'm making some fundamental mistake.

My file-structure:

```
gulpfile.js
spec/test.js
source/js/tictactoe.js
```

A simplified version of the code:

gulp:

```
gulp.task('site:js:test', function() {
return gulp.src( 'spec/test.js')
    .pipe(jasmine())});
```

test.js:

```
require("../source/js/tictactoe");

describe("Tictactoe", function() {
  var t = new Tictactoe();
  it("expects there to be able to add a mark", function() {
    t.addMark([0,0], 1);
    expect(t.board[0,0]).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

tictactoe.js

```
function Tictactoe(size) {
  this.size = size;

  // default variables:
  this.EMPTY = "";
  this.board = [];

  for ( var i = 0; i < this.size; i++ ) {
    this.board[i] = [];
    for ( var j = 0; j < this.size; j++) {
      this.board[i][j] = this.EMPTY;
    }
  }
}

Tictactoe.prototype.addMark = function(position, player)
{}
```

I've also tried `gulp.src( ['source/js/tictactoe.js', 'spec/test.js'] )` and then no require in the test.js. Also no success.
I've also tried `gulp-jasmine` and `gulp-jasmine-browser`. Can you help me make it work?

Thanks so much in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

A related question to yours has been answered already over here: [How to Load a File for Testing with Jasmine Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436416/how-to-load-a-file-for-testing-with-jasmine-node)

In short, you will need to create a module out of your tictactoe library, export the Tictactoe function, and then require it into a local variable that is accessible by Jasmine. The Tictactoe function is currently simply scoped into the local scope of the required JavaScript file.